# User management using chef

Tags: chef

I need to install a jenkins on a server using a user jenkinsuser and group jenkinsgroup. so in my recipe I defined as

```
#group
group jenkinsgroup do
  system true
end
# creates user
user jenkinsuser do
  gid jenkinsgroup
  system true
end
```

but what will happen if the user and group exist already in node (where I am trying to install jenkins) 
Does my resource do nothing as a user and group exists and go for next steps or will it throw an error as user exists?

Comment: Why don't you try it? Wouldn't have taken longer than writing this, right?

Comment: With chef, you define the desired state (e.g. a group exists). Therefore, it does nothing, if the system is already in the desired state.

Answer (score 6):

It does nothing. A huge part of the purpose of Chef is that converges are *[idempotent](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/idempotent)*, meaning you can run them repeatedly with no cumulative effects. I highly recommend consulting the [Chef documentation](https://docs.chef.io/) as it will provide an excellent foundation for understanding how and why Chef works.